# Is there any downside of using ultrasound guidance when performing injections to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, injections

The result of (1) published last week showed that when performing injections for tennis elbow, only 3 out of 10 were correctly localized (!). Is there any downside of using ultrasound guidance when performing injections to treat a tendinopathy? (aside from the cost of the ultrasound machine, which is actually pretty low, ~1kUSD)

---

- (1) Keijsers, R et al. Knee Surg Sports Traumatol Arthrosc (2016). Injection of tennis elbow: Hit and miss? A cadaveric study of injection accuracy
  doi:10.1007/s00167-016-4212-0 ; http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00167-016-4212-0 ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1007/s00167-016-4212-0

  > ​Result details:​
  >
  > ​Of the 10 performed injections, only 3 injections (30 %) were at least partially located at the ECRB (extensor carpi radialis brevis) tendon. Six (60 %) out of 10 injections were also located intra-articular. Six injections were located (totally or partially) at the ECRL (extensor carpi radialis longus) tendon. The acrylic dye was also located at the anconeus muscle (n = 3), lateral epicondyle (n = 3), triceps muscle (n = 2), brachioradialis muscle (n = 1). The number of perforations ranged from 1 to 10 and the amount of injected fluid ranged from 1 to 2 cc.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.